Bidirectional rsync synchronization
I have a problem with bidirectional rsync of data. I want to sync samba shares from two servers with each other, creating a mirror of each to the other, syncing once per day in the night. The schedule:
3:00 AM - /loc1 to /loc2
3:05 AM - /loc2 to /loc1
The problems:

people can change the same file on both servers, so it can overwrite changes from /loc1 to /loc2 when the file was edited on /loc2 and vice versa
when file was deleted on /loc2, it's still on /loc1, so it will be copied once again and vice versa
files may be open for write, and unavailable for copying

I am using the below commands:
rsync -avth --update --max-size=500m --exclude={'*exe','*msi','*zip'} --rsh=ssh -e "ssh -i key" /loc1 /loc2

or
rsync -avth --delete --max-size=500m --exclude={'*exe','*msi','*zip'} --rsh=ssh -e "ssh -i key" /loc1 /loc2

I think one server should be master, second one slave.
Am I right?
Or you have any idea how to sync it?

You might want to try software designed for bidirectional synchronisation, such as Unison.

Many tools for bidirectional synchronisation rely on user intervention to solve conflicting updates, which is an OK approach for a single user  but not for a shared file server.

Syncthing was made for that, except it syncs continuously, not once per n hours. It seems like a much better tool for your job.

↑ More importantly, Syncthing will retain both versions when a conflict occurs (allowing for manual merging), instead of having one side always lose.

A big downside of Syncthing is that it would lose any file ownership and ACLs. It's a user-oriented solution, designed to be operated by end user whose files need to be synced, not a system-oriented solution to be set up by system admin.

@NikitaKipriyanov: They added ownership sync a while ago as an option. I don't recall if they do ACLs.

@u1686_grawity it turned out yes, they added an option syncOwnership in version 1.21.0 in 2022. That's quite recently; they were long time reluctant to do this, as it was been requested at least since 2014. Honestly I ceased hoping by that time. They also added syncXattrs in a subsequent version, which must also sync ACLs on certain file systems, where ACLs stored as a special kind of xattrs, such as ext4. So, maybe, if the OP uses ext4, that is really an option.

@NikitaKipriyanov: ACLs are always exposed in the form of xattrs on Linux, that's the userspace API regardless of how the filesystem really stores them – but they're namespaced and I was assuming that Syncthing would only handle user.* xattrs and not the security.* or system.* ones, like many other such tools do (especially as many of the latter aren't "fully portable"). Though it doesn't look like Syncthing filters any xattrs by default, so it might successfully sync system.posix_acl_access (again regardless of FS) if syncXattrs is enabled, but I don't fully understand its code.

too long for a comment
IMHO The consistency issues you yourself have already raised should be a red flag that your approach is inherently flawed.
Most replication based strategies won't allow you to make changes on the destination, only on the source (file)system for exactly that reason.
Solutions that allow you/your users to concurrently and transparently read and write to an identical "local" file system from two (or more nodes) do exist.  But then you're usually talking about a cluster(ed) filesystem and cluster lock manager (that prevents the same files from being opened for read/write on more than 1 node at the same time)  such as for example the  Red Hat Global File System 2 (GFS2),   Oracle Cluster File System  2 (OCFS2) and/or others.  Such a cluster file system will be deployed on top of some form of either shared block storage (for example a shared SAN LUN, iSCSI target, shared SAS enclosure) or replicated block storage like a dual-primary DRBD resource.
Once established, as far as I know you, it is possible to  share that clustered file system over samba or NFS and you'll have two identical file shares that should always be in-sync in (close to) real time.

It sounds like what you actually need here is something completely different from what you have.
The first option is to force all but one of the copies to be read-only for everything except the synchronization process. That collapses things down to a single primary copy with one or more backups, as you suggest, which resolves both of the issues you outlined as well as a number you did not (such as the question of what happens where the first sync takes far longer than expected and is not finished by the time the reverse sync starts). The downside is that the primary copy needs to be accessible from everywhere things in it need to be modified (though this should not be a security issue, just a routing issue, if someone can modify a file on one copy in a bidirectional mirrored setup, there is no loss of security from allowing them to modify the same file in the other copy).
The second option is a clustered filesystem. In this case you can have both proper multi-device replication and not need to worry about conflicts, but it’s a lot more complicated to set up, and requires much more careful design to ensure reliability. Ceph is probably what I would use in this case (it has distinct advantages in that it does not require shared storage, does not require external metadata storage, and provides both native and NFS access to the data).
Finally, depending on what your specific needs are, you might find better results with a distributed version control system instead of a file server.

There is a solution to keep data in sync, a tool called csync2. It maintains a database to track changes on each node (it's worth noting that it can sync more than two systems). It wasn't designed for use with actively changing data. Instead, its primary purpose was to distribute clustered configurations, hence the name "cluster sync". Configurations rarely change, and almost never changes to occur concurrently, so no conflicts are expected.
Nevertheless, there was once an attempt to marry it with lsyncd, another tool that quickly detects the changes in data using system notifications (namely, inotify in Linux). It is written in Lua (or, at least, it supports Lua scripting), it normally works in a single direction (in a master-slave fashion) and uses rsync under the hood for actual synchronization. But when rsync is replaced with csync2 and lsyncd is started on both sides, with little tweaking it turned out to be possible to run it on two nodes, devising a "poor man's master-master file synchronization solution".
However, it's conflict prone, quite fragile and therefore quite hard to deploy and maintain. I once tried to employ this to implement a highly available web hosting farm and learned it's not the right way. If you wanna give it a try too, you can google search for csync2 + lsyncd and find articles like this one; while it seems to be exactly what you are looking for, I don't recommend implementing it in production.
Instead, look for ways to redesign your whole architecture so it won't rely on such arcane techniques, as described in other answers. In particular, take a look on GlusterFS. And remember, any proper clustered solution requires at least three nodes for proper operation.
